# Execute function in bash on every keystroke in interactive shell

Tags: bash, function, hook

I would like to run a function every time a user presses a key in an interactive bash shell.

I am wondering if bash has anything built in like the self-insert function in zsh?

Alternatively, I am wondering if there is some file descriptor I could read from that contains the buffer, similar to the $BUFFER variable in zsh?

Note: I am aware of this question: https://superuser.com/questions/604812/how-to-execute-a-function-in-bash-or-zsh-on-every-letter-being-typed-into-prompt.

I am looking to build something similar to the `script` command but without using pseudo-terminals

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but `read -n1` might work.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -n1 -r v
do
        printf 'You typed "%s".\n' "$v"
done
```

- The `-r` allows backslash (`\`) to work as an ordinary character.
- It needs to be tweaked for you to actually be able to see
  when the user types a space, tab or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
  (As it's written here, `read` will return but `$v` will not be set.)
- Special keys (like <kbd>F1</kbd>) will appear as multiple characters.
- The characters are displayed as the user types them, as usual. 
  You can turn that off with `stty -echo`.
- As the code is written here,
  you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break out of the loop. 
  Obviously you can add your own logic;
  e.g., `if [ "$v" = Q ]; then break; fi`.